# Firebase Push Notification click_action

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to open a particular page when the user clicks the notification when the app is in the background /foreground. From the Docs, I have got that click_action has to be added in the payload and an intent filter in the App to handle it. But i am unable to see any click_action functionality.

Comment: Hi, i think you might have the wrong tags attached